# Two clicks at back button are necessary to trigger popstate/statechange event

Tags: iframe, history, back-button, popstate

I have a page which contains an iframe. The iframe can take user's input (via button click or menu selection) and display content accordingly. 
What I need is, when a user manipulates the iframe, the browser push each set of iframe parameters into history; and when the user click at back button, the iframe will reload its content using the saved parameters from the previous history entry. I have a piece of code doing the reloading as shown below.

The strange thing is, when I make multiple settings on the iframe (hence multiple state entries added to history), and then click at back, it'll work like this,

Say that I have state 4, 3, 2 in history and I'm now at state 5

1. the first click restore to state 4 (the "----state changed----" logging message is printed
2. the second click reloads the iframe with default content. The "----state changed----" is not printed; the reloading code is not called.
3. the third click restore to state 3
4. the fourth click is like the 2nd click
5. the 5th click restore to state 2

So after each click that successfully restore the state, it takes two clicks to trigger the popstate event (I tried statechanged event, too, with same result) and restore to another previous state.

Anyone know what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, "popstate",
    function (event) {
        console.log("----state changed------", History.getState());   
        console.log("----state data------",History.getState().data.state);  

           //code to do reload an iframe to its proper state

    });
```

Answer (score 5):

So I stumbled on this same issue.  The situation we had was using `history.pushState()` to update the URL and then after that changing the `src` attribute of an `<iframe>`.  By changing the `src` of the `<iframe>`, we are implicitly telling the browser to add to its history that the iframe had changed.  Thus...

1. When we pressed back the first time, `window.history`'s popstate is
   triggered on the `<iframe>`'s src attribute and is reverted back to it's previous state.
2. Pressing back a second time triggers the `popstate` event for the state you originally pushed onto the stack

Our solution involved that when we decided to update the URL and push the state onto the stack, when we wanted to update the `<iframe>`, we used jQuery to replace the `<iframe>` list so...

```
$("#iFrameID").replaceWith(('<iframe id="iFrameID" src="' + location + '"></iframe>'
```

By doing this, we removed the side effect of the browser history getting polluted with our update to the `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: This won't work, if you want to to do more complicated stuff with your `iframe` such as POSTs. I mean it is possible, but it requires a very complete script (to handle all the edge cases) to do the POSTs via Ajax. At that point, you don't even need to set the iframe's url anymore, but just update it's contents, at which point this simple solution sadly has become moot. :/ I am still looking for an easier way to handle that...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.Instead of navigating the user to the previous page on the website, the back button navigated the user to the previous page inside the iframe. This code below will help you to solve your problem:

```
iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(href)
```